# How to quickly get a list of keys from dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I construct a dictionary from an excel sheet and end up with something like:

```
d = {('a','b','c'): val1, ('a','d'): val2}
```

The tuples I use as keys contain a handful of values, the goal is to get a list of these values which occur more than a certain number of times.

I've tried two solutions, both of which take entirely too long.

Attempt 1, simple list comprehension filter:

```
keyList = []
for k in d.keys():
    keyList.extend(list(k))

# The script makes it to here before hanging

commonkeylist = [key for key in keyList if keyList.count(key) > 5]
```

This takes forever since `list.count()` traverses the least on each iteration of the comprehension.

Attempt 2, create a count dictionary

```
keyList = []
keydict = {}
for k in d.keys():
    keyList.extend(list(k))

# The script makes it to here before hanging

for k in keyList:
    if k in keydict.keys():
        keydict[k] += 1
    else:
        keydict[k] = 1

commonkeylist = [k for k in keyList if keydict[k] > 50]
```

I thought this would be faster since we only traverse all of keyList a handful of times, but it still hangs the script.

**What other steps can I take to improve the efficiency of this operation?**

Comment: don't use .keys, that is creating a list. You also don't need to call list on k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a generator expression:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(item for key in d for item in key)
commonkkeylist = [item for item, count in counts.most_common() if count > 50]
```

where iterating over the dictionary directly yields the keys without creating an intermediary list object.

Demo with a lower count filter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {('a','b','c'): 'val1', ('a','d'): 'val2'}
>>> counts = Counter(item for key in d for item in key)
>>> counts
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
>>> [item for item, count in counts.most_common() if count > 1]
['a']
```

Comment: Why use `iterkeys()` at all? Iterating over a dict already iterates over the keys.

Comment: @stranac: see, that's what 2 hours at the pub does to you. Don't drink and code.

Comment: Runs like a dream, but I don't think I can responsible accept this answer due to moral exceptions with the state of the author :)

Comment: @wnnmaw: does that moral state change when I reveal it was all of one pint of bitter with a good lunch? :-) It's the done thing in the UK, to have lunch at the pub from time to time. We just took our time a little, today.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought this would be faster since we only traverse all of keyList a
>   handful of times, but it still hangs the script.

That's because you're still doing an O(n) search.  Replace this:

```
for k in keyList:
    if k in keydict.keys():
```

with this:

```
for k in keyList:
    if k in keydict:
```

and see if that helps your 2nd attempt perform better.